# Remove focus rectangle from radiobutton caption

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I want to remove the dotted focus rectangle of the caption from a radio button in my C++ Builder XE7 application, when the button is pressed. Is there a possibility to do this?

I want to remove this focus rectangle:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to create your own component and implement this behaviour. Another more easy but less professional way would be to remove the caption of the `TRadioButton` and place a `TLabel` next to it. Be sure that you really need this behaviour, because the rectangle is needed for keyboard navigation.

Comment: I hoped there is a "professional" way without customize the component. But it seems there is no way. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome! Normally the rectangle should not be displayed as long as you only navigate with the mouse through the UI. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: That´s correct. The rectangle is only displayed when you click on the compnent or when you select it with the TAB key. I want to remove it because its old fashioned ;-)

Comment: In Win7 the rectangle seems only to be shown when TAB is pressed but not when you only click on the control. Remember that users could use the keyboard for navigation and that they would be happy if they can see the focused control, even if it's old fashioned ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this method below:

```
JSpinner s1=new JSpinner("Example")
s1.setFocusPainted(false);
```